# Count of "Defined" Array Elements

Tags: javascript, undefined

Given following array:

```
var arr = [undefined, undefined, 2, 5, undefined, undefined];
```

I'd like to get the count of elements which *are* defined (i.e.: those which are *not* `undefined`).  Other than looping through the array, is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In recent browser, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var size = arr.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;

console.log(size);
```

Another method, if the browser supports [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for arrays:

```
var size = arr.slice(0).sort().indexOf(undefined);
```

If for absurd you have one-digit-only elements in the array, you could use that dirty trick:

```
console.log(arr.join("").length);
```

There are several methods you can use, but at the end we have to see if it's really worthy doing these instead of a loop.

Comment: nice solution,but in experience it is always better to take as generic an approach as possible. almost NEVER rely on a browser's javascript engine feature! ever. try and stay as conforming to standard javascript (ECMA) as possible and beware of newest standards as it takes a while for browsers to properly implement some features if ever. By using filter you exclude anybody who (heaven forbids) uses ie9< who is everybody still on win XP. Unfortunately even now in 2014 long after support ended for XP it is still the most popular desktop OS.  :(

Comment: As you said, we should try and stay conform to standard javascript (ECMAScript), I totally agree with you! And `filter` is part of ECMA. It's not so new either (ES5, not 6). And luckily, is one of the ES standard that can be easily polyfilled, compare to others. The link in my reply provides also the polyfill. If we're develop for the web, my suggestion is always include the polyfill for ES5 methods; block ourselves to ES3 nowadays makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

An array `length` is not the number of elements in a array, it is the highest `index + 1`. `length` property will report correct element count only if there are valid elements in consecutive indices.

```
var a = [];
a[23] = 'foo';
a.length;  // 24
```

Saying that, there is no way to exclude undefined elements from count without using any form of a loop.

Comment: without looping, you can filter out the undefined vals and get the size of that array. check my answer

Comment: @blackpla9ue, I'm considering only core JavaScript language without JQuery library. The question is tagged only javascript.

Comment: @blackpla9ue: Your approach loops, it just does it in jQuery code (originally) or within `filter` (your current update -- which doesn't work, btw).

Comment: filter is kind of loop

Answer (score 2):

No, the only way to know how many elements are not undefined is to loop through and count them. That doesn't mean *you* have to write the loop, though, just that something, somewhere has to do it. (See #3 below for why I added that caveat.)

How you loop through and count them is up to you. There are lots of ways:

1. A standard `for` loop from `0` to `arr.length - 1` (inclusive).
2. A `for..in` loop [provided you take correct safeguards](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).
3. Any of several of the new array features from ECMAScript5 (provided you're using a JavaScript engine that supports them, or you've included an ES5 shim, as they're all shim-able), like [`some`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.17), [`filter`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.20), or [`reduce`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.21), passing in an appropriate function. This is handy not only because you don't have to explicitly write the loop, but because using these features gives the JavaScript engine the opportunity to optimize the loop it does internally in various ways. (Whether it actually *does* will vary on the engine.)

...but it all amounts to looping, either explicitly or (in the case of the new array features) implicitly.

Comment: Do you count `Array.prototype.filter` as looping?

Comment: @RobG: I do, because [it's defined as a loop](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.20) and moreover, it's required to be generic. That doesn't mean that the browser's engine can't loop more quickly than the JavaScript code does (and in particular, using `filter` or similar allows the engine to optimize when it knows it's really dealing with an array and not an array-like object), but it's still a loop. Of course, in terms of what we actually write, it's less loopy than a `for` loop (one of many reasons I *love* the new stuff). You've inspired me to add a caveat, though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Loop and count in all browsers:

```
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
        ++cnt;
    }
}
```

In modern browsers:

```
var cnt = 0;
arr.foreach(function(val) {
    if (val !== undefined) { ++cnt; }
})
```

Comment: `!=` is not a good test for `undefined`, it will miscount `null`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - switched to `!==`.  I should know better!

Comment: Or, if you'd like to be one step more functional: var count = arr.reduce(function(counter, value) {
  return value === undefined ? counter : counter + 1;
});

Comment: @Jakob - are you sure that works?  The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) says that `reduce` skips holes in the array (which I assume are undefined elements).

Comment: @jfriend00: "Holes" are not the same as elements with the value `undefined`. The array the OP shows has no holes in it (it's not a sparse array).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I didn't think there really is such a thing as a sparse array in javascript.  Can you show me how you create one and how you would iterate only the existing array elements and how it would be different than the OP's array.

Comment: @jfriend00: JavaScript arrays are inherently sparse because [they're not really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). Example: http://jsbin.com/ikucoj The non-sparse array has an element with the key `0` (well, technically, `"0"`) which has the value `undefined`. The sparse array doesn't have an element with that key at all. You get `undefined` if you ask for that element because that's what you get any time you ask an object for a property it doesn't have, which is not the same as getting `undefined` because the property exists and has that value.

Comment: There is one minor quible: it won't tell the difference between a member whose value is *undefined* and one that hasn't been defined at all, e.g. `a = new Array(5);` has a length of 5 and no members at all. But likely the OP doesn't care. ;-)

Comment: regardless js obj.length / arr.length is an inadequate method and an actual counting method should have been included in standard ECMA ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No. You will you have to go through a loop and count them.

<strike>EDIT :</strike>

```
var arrLength = arr.filter(Number);
alert(arrLength);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I fixed the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: That's an ... interesting approach. It fails, mind, if one of the elements is `0` or `""` or `null` (gets the count wrong). And it relies on ES5, which it's best to [warn people you're doing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not). AND it's still looping, it's just doing it implicitly rather than explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If the undefined's are implicit then you can do:

```
var len = 0;
for (var i in arr) { len++ };
```

undefined's are implicit if you don't set them explicitly

```
//both are a[0] and a[3] are explicit undefined
var arr = [undefined, 1, 2, undefined];

arr[6] = 3;
//now arr[4] and arr[5] are implicit undefined

delete arr[1]
//now arr[1] is implicit undefined

arr[2] = undefined
//now arr[2] is explicit undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the values then check (remove null check here if you want)

```
const x = A.filter(item => item !== undefined || item !== null).length
```

With Lodash

```
const x = _.size(_.filter(A, item => !_.isNil(item)))
```