# Count the number of boolean values between two files

Tags: javascript

I would like to count the number of `true` boolean values.

For example, in `a.js`:

```
var countElement = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: true
}
```

there are two `true` values. How can I count the boolean variables in another JavaScript file, like `b.js`?

`countElement = 2`, is it possible do not change the a.js code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript count of array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901950/javascript-count-of-array-elements)

Answer (score 2):

You could count from another js file assuming that you run both of the scripts in the same HTML document and that `a.js` is loaded before `b.js`. If you declare a global variable in either of the files, they will be accessible from either script or from the console.

If you were to run them in NodeJS per say, you need to investigate module exports.