# Arrays - Length.unclear

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have this code :

```
var box = [];
box[0] = "meow";
box[3] = {"babyBox" : true};
```

Question :  Why  box[‘length’];  will show in the console 4 instead of 2?
I've changed the box[3] with box[10] and I get 11.
Sorry if this is a noob question..but from my point of view the array named box has only 2 elements.
Thank you very much!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9902083/2564301

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

> The length property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is
>   always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting `box[3]` which tells it there are 4 (0,1,2,3) parts to the array even if you haven't assigned anything to them yet

Answer (score 0):

The length is recalculated every time you add an element into the Array.

By assigning an item at an index which is beyond the length of the array, you caused the array to resize. The unassigned indexes become **holes** in an array.

Basically, now the Array looks like:

```
         0                     1                     2                     3
--------------------  --------------------  --------------------  -------------------- 
| "meow"           |  |                  |  |                  |  |{"babyBox" : true}|
--------------------  --------------------  --------------------  --------------------
```