# Javascript array non undefined element count

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create an array with `let arr = new Array(99999)` but I don't fill it up to `arr.length` which is `99999`, how can I know how much actual, non `undefined` elements do I have in this array?

Is there a better way than to look for the first `undefined`?

Comment: *Is there a better way than to look* for this we would need your code to compare if our approach is better or worse. Also a user with your rep should know the importance of code

Comment: My approach is `arr.indexOf("undefined")` @Rajesh

Comment: Please share it in question as that would help everyone who reads your question

Comment: It doesn't actually work though and I hoped to avoid having to loop through the array. @Rajesh

Comment: Dear friend, your code doesn't work is the main reason this post exists. If you would have shared your code, we could have added more information as to what you have mistaken and how to correct it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count of "Defined" Array Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901950/count-of-defined-array-elements)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which skips sparse elements.

```js
let array = new Array(99999),
    count = 0;

array[30] = undefined;

array.forEach(_ => count++);

console.log(count);
```

The same with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let array = new Array(99999),
    count = 0;

array[30] = undefined;

count = array.reduce(c => c + 1, 0);

console.log(count);
```

For filtering non sparse/dense elements, you could use a callback which returns for every element `true`.

Maybe this link helps a bit to understand the mechanic of a sparse array: [JavaScript: sparse arrays vs. dense arrays](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html).

```js
let array = new Array(99999),
    nonsparsed;

array[30] = undefined;

nonsparsed = array.filter(_ => true);

console.log(nonsparsed);
console.log(nonsparsed.length);
```

Comment: @Mistalis, it depends on the cout of sparsed elements, if you have only one with value, like above then any array method would be faster, then looping from zero to `99999`.

Comment: How does `(_ => true);` return the right result? this function always return true no?

Comment: it returns all **nonsparsed** elements of the array, even the ones with **value** `undefined`.

Comment: What do you mean by "nonsparsed" elements? You mean it returns the first continuous batch of elements in the array? Also this function always return true so it shouldn't filter out `undefined` elements, but it does, how?

Comment: it returns for **every** found (nonsparsed) item `true`, it does not make a check, just return `true`. the value of the item does not matter.

Comment: But there's isn't even a return and it doesn't use the argument. Is this some quirk or hack of js? Why use these things anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139939/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-kuhaku).

Comment: @kuhaku, it is an ES6 standard: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 6):

The fastest & simplest way to [filter items in an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is to... well... use the  `.filter()` function, to filter out only the elements that are valid (non undefined in your case), and then check the `.length` of the result...

```js
function isValid(value) {
  return value != undefined;
}
var arr = [12, undefined, "blabla", ,true, 44];
var filtered = arr.filter(isValid);

console.log(filtered);   // [12, "blabla", true, 44]
```

Comment: for counting only, a new array is a bit over the top.

Comment: My end goal was to reduce the size of the array to its actual size, and looks like filter is super fast which is great. @NinaScholz

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean?