# using spread syntax and formatting in javascript array string substitution

Tags: javascript

if I have an array like this `[1,2,3]` and I want to use it to fill a string like:

`the values are (?, ?, ?)`

is there an easy way to do this?

I know you can use `...[1,2,3]` to spread, and it's easy enough to convert the array to `['?', '?', '?']`, but it won't work when I do something like:

```
the values are (${...['?', '?', '?']})
```

Comment: Do you want `?`s or the values?

Comment: try `"The values are (" + array.map(x=>"?").join() + ")"`

Comment: @Rajesh: I don't know why it's never occurred to me to use a single-character throwaway parameter name instead of `()` in that situation. Nice! I'll have to think about it. `_` is the traditional "I'm not going to use this," but I wonder whether `.map(_ => "?")` is a bit...symbol-heavy...and your `x` might be better in this context. Or it may be that if I use `_ => ...` enough, I'll get used to it and the symbol-heaviness won't be an issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess I'm just being lazy. Also I think its better to use `(x)=>` instead of `x=>`. `(..)` at least looks like argument list and might make code more readable. But its just my POV. The whole brevity thing has added so much grey area in JS coding

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i use it to count/filter sparsed arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224580/javascript-array-non-undefined-element-count/43224640#43224640

Answer (score 1):

Spread doesn't really come into it for doing this.

It's not clear from the question whether you want `?`, literally, in the string, or the values from the array. So both:

---

If you really want `?` (literally), `map` with `join` does it:

```
`the values are (${theArray.map(() => "?").join(", ")})`
```

```js
var theArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(`the values are (${theArray.map(() => "?").join(", ")})`);
```

Or perhaps `String#repeat` with a `slice` removing the last delimiter:

```
`the values are (${"?, ".repeat(theArray.length).slice(0, -2)})`
```

```js
var theArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(`the values are (${"?, ".repeat(theArray.length).slice(0, -2)})`);
```

---

If you want the values, then just `join`:

```
`the values are (${theArray.join(", ")})`
```

```js
var theArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(`the values are (${theArray.join(", ")})`);
```